# 'Remove' command for ND arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, set-intersection

I have two arrays

```
A=np.array([[2,0],
            [3,4],
            [5,6]])
```

and

```
B=np.array([[4,3],
            [6,7],
            [3,4],
            [2,0]])
```

I want to essentially subtract B from A and obtain indices of elements in A which are present in B. How do I accomplish this? In this example, I need answers like:

```
C=[0,1] //index in A of elements repeated in B 
D=[[2,0], [3,4]] //their value 
E=[3,2] //index location of these in B
```

Several usual commands like nonzero, remove, filter, etc seem unusable for ND arrays. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Do you mean you want the rows in `B` that are also in `A`, and the row index of the rows in each array? That's not what is usually meant by elements, or subtraction - try e.g. `[(i, r) for i, r in enumerate(A) if r in B]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a data type that will be the concatenation of your columns, allowing you to use the 1d set operations:

```
a = np.ascontiguousarray(A).view(np.dtype((np.void, A.shape[1]*min(A.strides))))
b = np.ascontiguousarray(B).view(np.dtype((np.void, B.shape[1]*min(B.strides))))

check = np.in1d(a, b)
C = np.where(check)[0]
D = A[check]

check = np.in1d(b, a)
E = np.where(check)[0]
```

If you wanted only `D`, for example, you could have done:

```
D = np.intersect1d(a, b).view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, A.shape[1])
```

note in the last example how the original dtype can be recovered.